# How do I register the worker notary nodes in a Corda Enterprise HA Cluster?

Tags: corda, enterprise

When I follow the directions in https://docs.corda.r3.com/running-a-notary-cluster/installing-the-notary-service-bootstrapper.html

I get the error shown below. This happens both when I try using just “generate_node_info” as well as the general bootstrapper command. The reason is that I already have the O=Notary name registered as the notary and its certificate is in the *.jks file in the certificates directory. What I need is to get the worker nodes registered. That does not seem to work. It expects the name to already match what is in the certificates.

```
[1;31m[ERROR] 17:51:20-0500 [main] internal.Node.run - Exception during node startup
    [m net.corda.node.internal.ConfigurationException: The name 'O=Notary-1, L=London, C=GB' for identity doesn't match what's in the key store: O=Notary, L=London, C=GB
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.obtainIdentity(AbstractNode.kt:945) ~[corda-node-3.2.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.generateAndSaveNodeInfo(AbstractNode.kt:213) ~[corda-node-3.2.jar:?]
```

Comment: Can you post the `node.conf` contents for two of the worker nodes, please?

Comment: I can give you all three. FYI.. since I posted this, a Jira support request SUP-452 was opened by Lamar. The configuration files are redacted so that confidential information is not revealed.

Comment: I can't add that many characters, but I think this is the part you are looking for.            "notary" : {
        "mysql" : {
          "connectionRetries" : 3 
          "dataSource" : {
            "autoCommit" : false
            "jdbcUrl" : "jdbc:mysql://{PERCONA_SERVER_DB}?rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useSSL=false&failOverReadOnly=false"
            "username" : "{mysql_user}"
            "password" : "{mysql_pwd}"
          }
        }
        "validating" : false
        "serviceLegalName" : "O=Notary, C=GB, L=London"
    }

Comment: Can you check whether your notary.serviceLegalName and myLegalName are different in the configuration file?

Comment: Yes, they are different.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming up to this question, it falls under the same umbrella as most Corda enterprise issues where they're so specific that you're better off contacting R3 enterprise support.

This particular question I believe is being handled by the support team so if you're using Corda Enterprise you'd be better off doing the same thing.

Best of luck and thanks.